# Login & Registration same scripts, but one doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So part of the first script that processes registrations looks like this:

```
  var dataString = 'fullnames='+ fullnames + '&phone=' + phone + '&emails=' + emails + '&passs=' + passs + '&page=signup';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save_details.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() 
        {
            $("#signup_status").html('<br clear="all"><div style="padding-left:115px;"><font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:black;">
            Wait a bit
            </font> <img src="images/loadings.gif" alt="Se proceseaza...." align="absmiddle" title="Se proceseaza...."/></div><br clear="all">');
        },
        success: function(response)
        {
            $("#signup_status").hide().fadeIn('slow').html(response);
        }
    });
```

The other script that processes the login form looks quite the same

```
var dataString = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&page=login';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() 
            {
                $("#login_status").html('<br clear="all"><div style="padding-left:115px;"><font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:black;">
                Wait a bit
                </font> <img src="images/loadings.gif" alt="Se proceseaza...." align="absmiddle" title="Se proceseaza...."/></div><br clear="all">');
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                $("#login_status").hide().fadeIn('slow').html(response);
            }
        });
```

the first one works without any problems, but the 2nd one will show "Wait a bit" and just stay there forever even though it parses the data to the php script and creates the session in order to log in but will not show the success message and idles to "Wait a bit".

Comment: Is the server returning a `200 OK`?

Comment: Basically the 2nd script stays at the beforeSend function while first goes to success.

Comment: Add an error callback and check the results.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, i had the following problem, on the processing php script instea of:

**$_SESSION["USER_FULLNAME"] = $checkmail->name;**

i had

**$_SESSION["USER_FULLNAME"] = $$checkmail->name;**

A dollar waisted hours.